# JSQ message - Swift 3 "didPressSendButton"

Tags: swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I´m trying to make a simple chat with JSQ Message.
Whenever I use the send button, the app crash.
It worked fine in the terminal, but after I wanted it to be displayed in the view, I keep getting this message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error! required method not implemented in subclass. Need to implement -[JSQMessagesViewController didPressSendButton:withMessageText:senderId:senderDisplayName:date:]'

Here is my controller:

[image: controller 1/2]
[image: controller 2/2]

Comment: Get rid off `!` after type in function parameters, they're not nullable. At least in latest JSQMessagesViewController version.

Comment: I tried that, but it did not help

Comment: Can you ⌘-click on `JSQMessagesViewController ` and check how `didPressSendButton` is defined there?

Comment: I worked before I updated to Swift 3. Could that be the reason ?????

Answer (score 3):

Working with: Swift 3.0 & JSQMessagesViewController 7.3.4

```
override func didPressSend(_ button: UIButton!, withMessageText text: String!, senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: Date!) {
        let message = JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, senderDisplayName: senderDisplayName, date: date, text: text)
        //ex: self.messages.append(message!)
        self.finishSendingMessage()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Now I just have to figure out, how to display the message in til BubbleImage. Any ideas ????

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea, but please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Thanks. It worked. Now I just have to figure out, how to display the message in til BubbleImage. Any ideas ????

When you delete "override" words, the Xcode error disappears.

But, This causes problems.

You must override each method.
Please be careful such as !, ? and _.

Working with: Swift 3.0 & JSQMessagesViewController 7.3.4

```
// MARK: - JSQMessage
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    code
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, avatarImageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource! {
    code
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageBubbleImageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> JSQMessageBubbleImageDataSource! {
    code
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> JSQMessageData! {
    code
}

override func didPressSend(_ button: UIButton!, withMessageText text: String!, senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: Date!) {
    code
}
```